# workaround for missing let in xpath 2.0?

Tags: xpath-2.0

Let's consider the following xml:

```
<a>
    <b id="1"/>
    <b id="2"/>
</a>
```

I understand that for a single value I can use

```
for $a in //b[@id=1] return $a
```

instead of the xpath 3.0 expression

```
let $a := //b[@id=1] return $a
```

But how can I put a sequence to the variable using for?

obviously

```
for $a in //b return $a[2]
```

will return nothing, so it is not a good replacement for

```
let $a := //b return $a[2]
```

I tried to construct a sequence where //b is the first element, and () is the second, and use it, but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: Well, in XSLT you can always use `xsl:variable` at the XSLT level instead of trying to use `let` at the XPath level. I can't see in your simple sample why you need or think you need a `for` expression at all, isn't `(//b)[2]` all you want?

Comment: Sure, but this is a pure xpath environment. I ended up implementing a function with the same functionality. Fortunately I have already implemented an evaluate function.

Comment: Why is the question tagged as [tag:xslt-2.0] if it is about pure XPath?

Comment: It was clearly a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
 for $len in count(/*/b),
     $ind in 1 to $len
   return
      (/*/b)[$ind]
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "for $len in count(/*/b),
         $ind in 1 to $len
       return
          (/*/b)[$ind] "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b id="1"/>
    <b id="2"/>
</a>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated** and the sequence that is the result of this evaluation is output:

```
<b id="1"/>
<b id="2"/>
```